# Using InetAddress to gather network interfaces

Tags: java, networking

I have used InetAddress as an array. However if i do not use array, I am able to print each network interface in the loop. Though I am iterating the array of InetAddress, the code shows nothing. Is there a fundamental problem? I am very new to networking world in java.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Interface_Enumeration_Concept {
   InetAddress[] address;
   public void GetInterfaces(){
    try {
        Enumeration interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface intf = (NetworkInterface) interfaces.nextElement();
            Enumeration addresses = intf.getInetAddresses();
            int i=0;
            while (addresses.hasMoreElements()){
                address[i] = (InetAddress) addresses.nextElement();
                System.out.println(address[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }catch(SocketException exp){
        exp.getCause();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interface_Enumeration_Concept objects = new Interface_Enumeration_Concept();
    objects.GetInterfaces();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A `SocketException` is occurring.  You do not print it, or do anything with it, so nothing happens afterwards, and you do not see it.  If instead of `exp.getCause()` (which does nothing) you do something like `exp.printStackTrace()` you will see the problem.

Comment: And when you fix that you will get a `NullPointerException` because you haven't initialized `address`.

Comment: Yeah I havent. In the networking fundamentals of java book by Pitt. He as not initialized the InetAddress by its constructor . Simply declared it and stuffed  the value. it worked